# sensu multiple instances on same server

Tags: linux, multiple-instances, sensu

Is it possible to run multiple instances of the sensu server on the same box? The intention is to have a "development" monitoring server to split the clients away from the production servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can as long as they all point to different places.. Like your config for production might look like

```
{
  "rabbitmq": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5672,
    "vhost": "/sensu",
    "user": "sensu",
    "password": "password"
  },
  "redis": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 6379
  },
  "api": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "bind": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 4567
  }
}
```

And for development

```
{
  "rabbitmq": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5672,
    "vhost": "/sensu-dev",
    "user": "sensu-dev",
    "password": "password"
  },
  "redis": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 6380
  },
  "api": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "bind": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 4568
  }
}
```

Pretty much you can run a single rabbit server with 2 vhosts and 2 user accounts. You'd need 2 redis servers running and 2 api servers.

Comment: so far it works, except the api. can not get a second instance tp start up. do i need  a second init script?